# Developers "spamming" on App Store

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I have developed five apps with name of five different football teams. Which shows event schedule of respective team. Apple rejected all of them and giving reason 
"Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program"

Now, I have seen following Apps are almost same and available on AppStore

```
http://itunes.apple.com/pk/app/brookwood-medical-center/id434593012?mt=8
http://itunes.apple.com/pk/app/doctors-hospital-of-manteca/id430928072?mt=8

http://itunes.apple.com/pk/app/doctors-medical-center-modesto/id447790452?mt=8
```

Now what is developer spamming? Anybody can explain it?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a technical question, but it is probably related to your code, so :

I think Apple rejects your applications for that reason when you use the same code base (or a close code base) for multiple applications, presented as different apps.

they must be thinking your are creating the same app under different names to gain more visibility in the store.

You should contact them and try to explain your case, or change your apps code and UI significantly enough to prove them these apps are different.

Answer (score 2):

Create *one* football app and allow the user to buy teams as in app purchases.

Let the user have one team included in the price of the app.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I have seen following Apps are almost same and available on AppStore

This is a common mistake.  You can not use the existence of apps in the iOS App Store as any sort of precedent.  These apps may have been accepted by accident, or under a previous interpretation of Apple's rules, which will not apply to your submissions.

Go by the current interpretation of the App store guidelines.

Maybe sell your apps to the respective teams so that you won't be submitting multiple apps, or running into any trademark licensing problems.

Answer (score 0):

"Developer spamming" as explained by [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar apps
>   will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

Comment: Sadly not really enforced.